# Cannot add sidebar to a DNN page

Tags: module, dotnetnuke

I cannot add an HTML module as a sidebar to a DotNetNuke page. I can drag n drop to to other places but not into the empty space on right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a PANE there for you to use? If so, check for Javascript errors. If not, you'll need to modify your skin.